# In roc auc curve, why we are considering only 1column of predict proba and how it is going to compute?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, naivebayes, roc, auc

In roc auc curve, why we are considering only 1-column of predict_proba and how it is going to compute tpr and fpr from 1-column of predict_proba? and what is the need of roc and auc ? can we improve our model by looking at it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. It is very unclear to me what the question is. Have a look at our help center to learn how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: fpr,tpr,threshold=roc_curve(y_test,y_preds[:,1])
roc_auc=metrics.auc(fpr,tpr)

Comment: y_preds[:,1] why we want only 1 column only .. to calculate tpr and fr it would need both columns of predict_proba , then why we took only 1 column... and how it is computing FPR AND TPR ?

Comment: consider editing your question to add this information.